# How to plot with mplot3d

Tags: python, mplot3d

I am trying to plot the solutions of a minimization problem,

```
'X, Y = meshgrid(gammas, psis)'
```

gammas and psis are my 2 axes,

```
'mplot3d(X, Y, x)'
```

x is the solution of my problem, 
While executing my script : name 'mplot3d' is not defined......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pylab
def scatterme(x, y, z):
    pylab.figure()
    imi = pylab.scatter(x, y, c = z, edgecolor = "none")
    pylab.colorbar(imi)
    pylab.show()
```

In this case, my `x` and `y` are what for you would be `X.flatten()` and `Y.flatten()` and the `z` would be your `x.flatten()`. This code also works if your data does not come from something square, so if you just want to see what something looks like, if you have a lot of x and y values, and for each one you have a z, this shows you what you want as well.

Note: this is not a 3D plot, but i (personnal opinion) feel that a scatterplot in which the z-dimension is your colorbar seems to show much more what you need to know, compared to a 3D plot that you have to rotate around all the time, to be able to see at the angle that might show you something you want to know

Edit: 
for the full code, that you can just copypaste (put this after the first piece in my post)

```
import numpy
X,Y = meshgrid(gammas, psis)
scatterme(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), x.flatten())
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you mean by numpy.flatten and why are you introducing new variables x,y,z

Comment: @Abdallah What are your X,Y,x ? They are numpy.ndarrays i guess? and new variables are used here since i use this piece of code as well for stuff in which my x,y are not from something like a square where you have a datapoint everywhere, so it is more general in its use. Edit: i updated my solution so you can just copypaste it to try and see if you like this way of visualization.

Comment: gammas is include in [0,pi/2] same for psis, 
I substitute x with gammas, y with psis, z with x, after executing this programm i see no plot is it normal ?

Comment: @Abdallah i updated my post a little, try again with the updated version?

Comment: After executing i have this error : 'module' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Comment: @Abdallah i updated it, with the correct Y.flatten() instead of numpy.flatten(Y) - does it work now? Note: i know i should move this to chat, but Abdallah does not have enough rep on this site to be able to talk in chat